# prime divisor of integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime and $N$ an integer. If $p\mid N$, then it is impossible for it to divide $N+1$? I simply thought that using modular arithmetic, if $p\mid N \rightarrow N \equiv 0 \mod p$  so if  $p\mid(N+1) \rightarrow N+1 \equiv 0 \mod p$, which is a contradiction. The reason I am asking is if I have two positive integers, $x,y$ with $y>x$ and $\frac{y+1}{x}=2$, does this imply that $\gcd(x,y)=1$?

Comment: Your congruences are flipped it should say $N\equiv 0\mod p$

Comment: thank you i edited it

Comment: $d\mid x,y\,\Rightarrow\, d\mid 2x-y = 1,\ $ so $\,x,y\,$ are coprime. This is the trivial direction of Bezout's GCD identity $\, \gcd(x,y)=1\iff jx+ky = 1\,$ for some integers $\,j,k\ \ \ $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes. If $p\mid\gcd(x,y)$ then you have $x\equiv y\equiv 0\mod p$. So, in one hand you have $$y\equiv 0\mod p.$$But on the other hand you have $$y=2x-1\equiv 2(0)-1\equiv -1\mod p$$ a contradiction.

So $\gcd(x,y)=1$